# How can I logout of Dart Pub CLI?

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I published a package and logged into the wrong account. I corrected the uploaders by using

```
flutter packages pub uploader add <correct email>
flutter packages pub uploader remove <incorrect email>
```

But now when I try to push an update I am unauthorized because I'm still logged in as the incorrect email.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be a file

```
~/.pub-cache/credentials.json
```

that holds your current authentication info.
If you remove that you should be requested to login again.

**Update**

A `pub logout` command was just added https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/2035

Comment: This hasn't been implemented yet and I am on latest dart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flutter SDK, the `.pub-cache` directory is actually inside the `flutter` directory. For my laptop, I have downloaded Flutter into `/home/username/flutter`: in order to reset credentials for commands like `flutter packages pub publish`, I had to delete `/home/username/flutter/.pub-cache`.